# Django: change project name static error

Tags: django, static

I just changed my project name from `ecommerce` to `my_project`. I went through every file (using a find feature) and did changed ecommerce to my_project. Now when I try to run it I get the following error from the command line:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 
  ...
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 102, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 117, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 238, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 504, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 467, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ecommerce'
```

Furthermore the error on the page is: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/stripe-custom-style.css' %}">` Is something wrong with static? I'm not sure what it could be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that Django is still trying to dynamically import the `ecommerce` module:

```
File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\storage.py", line 504, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 467, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "C:\\Dev\my_project\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
```

You should check if `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and/or `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` settings still point to the old package name.